# Is there any better idea to reverse a video and save it with and without voice?

Tags: windows, linux, video, video-editing, video-conversion

What kind of programming language we have to use for this process or any free softwares are available ?

Comment: What operating system do you prefer?

Comment: For linux and windows

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [reverse the video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_video), you can use the [Invert filter from VirtualDub](http://members.chello.at/nagiller/vdub/readme.html). From the video menu, you have access to the filters. From the audio menu, you can choose whether or not to process audio. You can download [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) and find tons of tutorials on Google as well as their site on how to use it.

Comment: no better solution than virtualdub - its amazing that program

Comment: ... sadly enough, that wasn't one of the two possible meanings of reverse i was thinking of. I was thinking left/right inversion or running the video backwards...

Comment: I agree, Journeyman Geek. I feel what this fellow wants to do should be called "Inverse Video".

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: The left/right inversion is called flipping, where the last one is usually called backwards playing the video. Back in the days this is what reversing a video is and it probably still is now. But indeed, the OP could specify what he is after because it is a confusing term.